# Display feched data on tagsInput using jQuery /Laravel8

Tags: jquery, laravel, tags

I have the following value in my database :

```
["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]
```

I get this value from database and I want to display this values on a tag inputs.

So I'm using the follwing jQuery code :

```
$("input[data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput('removeAll');
$("input[data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput('add',  html.data.adm_email);
```

I'm getting the following result :

[image]

So how can I get the foolowing result instead :

[image]

So how can I remove the `["` from data displayed.

If you have any idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$.each(tags, function(i,v){
   $("input[data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput('add',v);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to show this data with jquery

Comment: I have this value : `["hajar@gmail.com","khadija@gmail.com"]` ,And I should display it on tags input

Comment: ["hajar@gmail.com","khadija@gmail.com"].forEach((element)=>{console.log(element)})